# How to generate A4 size paginated pdf in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am generating pdf in nodejs using phantomjs. However, when I try to generate a large pdf (more than 1 A4 size page), it generates only two page pdf. One of the page contains all the matter and the other similar sized (very large) page is blank.

I am using the following code to generate the pdf:

```
phantom.create("--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",function(ph) {
return ph.createPage(function(page) {
return page.open(htmlfilepath, function(status) {
    page.paperSize = { format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm' };

    page.render(pdffilepath, function(){
      ph.exit();
    });
  });
});
});
```

Can anyone tell the correct method to format pdf in phantomjs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Even though I did exactly according to many articles and tutorial online, I had to use change the following piece to code:

```
page.paperSize = { format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm' };
```

to this:

```
 page.set('paperSize', { format: 'A4', orientation: 'portrait', border: '1cm'});
```

This may be because of the change in version from 1.x.x to 2.x.x.